# BHU 2017 ques. (Linear Transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

- Let $T\in(V,W),\;\dim V=5,\;\dim W=2,$ s.t. $T(V)\subset W\;\land\; T(V)\;$ isn't a singleton. Then the nullity of $T$ is:

a) $4$  b)$3$  c)$2$  d)$1$

- according to me- as $T(V)\subset W$  and not a Singleton so it must be $\dim T(V)=1$ (0 dimension is possible only in Zero transformation-transformation matrix will be zero matrix that has rank 0). Then nullity (T)= 5-1=4

Is anything wrong here??

Comment: No, nothing's wrong.

Comment: Range of a linear operator is always a vector space, so if it's a (proper) subset of $W$, which is a vector space, you can immediately write $Im V\lt W$

Comment: How can $\dim T(V)=0$ be possible in the identity transformation? Did you mean $Ker (T)=0$ in the identity transformation?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya Oh.. I'm sorry.. I was thinking zero transformation but i wrote identity transformation by mistake.. I will edit it and correct it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Some people interpret $\subset$ to mean proper subset, but some just use it to mean subset. With the latter interpretation, the dimension of $T(V)$ could be two

Comment: @GerryMyerson It's Proper Subset. And in that case dimension can't be 2. Right??

Comment: That's correct.